# Is it possible to disable the change of password email and send one via another system?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to disable the standard Wordpress changed password (to the user) and send an email via a different system (in this case Send In Blue).

I've had a look around and found that this disables the email

```
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

This is my code to send a particular template from Send in Blue:

```
$master->sendinblue_send_template($user_info->user_email, 34);
```

How can I combine the two? So when a user resets their password, the Send in Blue template is sent to them instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function and then call that function in your filter.

```
 function send_custom_mail () 
    {
       $res = sendinblue_send_template($user_info->user_email, 34); 
       return false;
    }

    add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', 'send_custom_mail ');
```

Comment: How can I parse the user's email address to that?